# PHP MySQL - number of records as an integer

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the number of records in my database as an integer and use it in PHP to set certain conditions. My code consists of the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM sql_table";
$records = $conn->query($sql);
$record_count = $records->fetch_assoc();
```

I did a `var_dump` of `$record_count` and it returned an array: `array(1) { ["COUNT(id)"]=> string(1) "4" }`. What I can't do is just access the number 4. I can access `string(1) "4"` by accessing `$record_count['COUNT(id)']`, but I can't find a way to access the number 4. If I try indexing, as in `$record_count['COUNT(id)'][11]`, I get nothing. This value does not appear to be a straight string.
How can I access the number of records in the table as an integer for use in PHP?

Comment: Try aliasing `COUNT()`: `COUNT(id) as count`. Then access it as `$record_count['count']`. You can cast it then to `int` with `(int)$record_count['count']` or using `intval`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way, but it's better to either use the internal num_rows in my opinion, or to do bind_result() to access COUNT(id) instead of using fetch assoc. That's just my style though :) This should work just fine for you.

```
$query = $sql->prepare("SELECT id FROM sql_table");
$query->execute();
$query->store_result();
$results = $query->num_rows;
$query->close();

echo $results;
```

Comment: Of course. I hadn't thought of num_rows. That works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @Dylan_Oscar See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer

Comment: Not sure @Dylan_Oscar, I just decided to sign up today... but I am glad it worked for you :)

Comment: The post linked to by @chris85 explains this. The code is working nicely now. Thanks.